# Speed up transfer of rows to another sheet based on cell value in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.
I am looking at transferring rows of data into a new spreadsheet based on a cells value.
I have been able to identify with the help on this site what I need to achieve, but I will be using a larger set of data in the future so want to ensure that the code can handle the large amounts of data.

[Copy From this Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JGxaHjOeCfQsaNWa2vxE1K7ndVLYgH6GCwVcllUI6jo/edit#gid=0)
[Paste to this Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxR-L2-Tj7slZQ0NMbQl0-JXZ8iVO59410ccVNZk7Ys/edit#gid=0)

```js
function transfer() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('COPY'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('A2:E'); 
 var data = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <data.length; ++i){
   var row = data[i];
   var check = row[4];

   var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qxR-L2-Tj7slZQ0NMbQl0-JXZ8iVO59410ccVNZk7Ys");
   var ts = tss.getSheetByName('PASTE');

   if (check == "Y") {
     ts.appendRow(row);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Since you’re just going to append all of rows to bottom of the data in the PASTE sheet then I would consider collecting all of your data in an Object[][] (i.e. 2D array) and use Range.setValues() to insert data all at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using up most of your time opening and appending the row. This are very time expensive calls. It's much faster to push all the rows you want to a new array and just set that array at the end.

```
function transfer() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('COPY'); 
  var range = ss.getRange('A2:E'); 
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qxR-L2-Tj7slZQ0NMbQl0-JXZ8iVO59410ccVNZk7Ys");
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('PASTE');

  var outArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <data.length; ++i){
    var row = data[i];
    if (row[4] == "Y") {
      outArray.push(row);
    }
  }

  ts.getRange(1, 1, outArray.length, outArray[0].length).setValues(outArray);
}
```

Give this a try and it should really speed things up. I would also recommend using TRUE or FALSE values to determine which rows you want to keep

Comment: Note that your code does not append to the target sheet, but instead overwrites existing data.

Comment: @tehhowch Is there a way to do this, as I want the data to be added to the end of the current log.

Comment: @PaulMarvell of course. It should be apparent that, if you do not want to overwrite data, then the `Range` one accesses must not be hard-coded, but must ask the sheet which row is the last row with data in it, and then start in the next row. (Replace "row" with "column" in that sentence if you are expanding horizontally instead of vertically). The Apps Script documentation for the Sheet class will be a great place to start. Here the range is hard-coded to always start in cell A1.